# How do I add emojis to my tokenizer in masked language modelling using BERT?

Tags: python, machine-learning, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I am new to using Hugging Face and BERT, and I am trying to make an attempt at doing some masked language modelling (MLM) using my own dataset. My own dataset contains about 20,000 tweets including emojis.

An example of a tweet is something like this:

```
@John123 I am so annoyed with you
```

Using masked language modelling, I want to do something where I mask the emoji token by replacing them with `[MASK]`. However, I am unsure how to add the emojis to my tokenizer - is there a way to do this?

At the moment, when I do this, the output does not seem to predict emojis. Instead, it just does something like this below.

Input:

```
The weather is bad today [MASK]
```

Actual output:

```
The weather is bad today.
```

Anticipated output:

```
The weather is bad today
```

I know that I am close to achieving what I want, but I need some additional guidance on how to actually accomplish this.

I have referred to [this](https://huggingface.co/blog/how-to-train) tutorial, which uses special tokens, but not emojis. Below, is the code used in that tutorial for special tokens:

```
from pathlib import Path

from tokenizers import ByteLevelBPETokenizer

paths = [str(x) for x in Path("./eo_data/").glob("**/*.txt")]

# Initialize a tokenizer
tokenizer = ByteLevelBPETokenizer()

# Customize training
tokenizer.train(files=paths, vocab_size=52_000, min_frequency=2, special_tokens=[
    "<s>",
    "<pad>",
    "</s>",
    "<unk>",
    "<mask>",
])
```

I think that I need to use this piece of code, but modify it for emojis - though, I am unsure how to do that.

Any help would be good, thanks!

Comment: It feels like the 3rd post that I read about emojis and huggingface. You do not want to train your own tokenizer. Just use [add_tokens()](https://huggingface.co/transformers/internal/tokenization_utils.html?highlight=add_tokens#transformers.tokenization_utils_base.SpecialTokensMixin.add_tokens) and why do you not formulate it as a classification task instead of MLM?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I am unsure how to do it as a classification task as supposed to MLM. So would I do it like this? ```num_added_toks = tokenizer.add_tokens(['', ''])```

Comment: [Sequnece classification](https://huggingface.co/transformers/custom_datasets.html#sequence-classification-with-imdb-reviews). It is enough when you do: `tokenizer.add_tokens(['', ''])`.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Also, now that you mention it, I think it might be relevant to use sequence classification, as all the emojis are at the end of each tweet - for example: "Looking good today ." So, would sequence classification be able to learn that the emojis are at the end of each tweet?

Comment: Sequence classification will not learn anything about the position. It will learn that `Looking good today` should be classified as . You have to contact the label  with the sentence after the prediction.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean... So, for each emoji, it needs a label? Like, for example, if I have 10 different emojis, I need 10 labels, each corresponding to an emoji?

Comment: Each emoji is a label by itself. Your model isn't aware of them anyway because it only knows the maximum number of labels.

Comment: Does all the emojis need to be manually extracted to become a label?

Comment: No, since you know where they are in your strings and you can simply extract them.